# Why won't Swift run from the CLI?

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, command-line

I can't get Xcode CLI to work. Every time I run "swift" I get this message:

```
error: failed to launch REPL process: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)
```

I've tried

```
sudo Xcode-select -s ~/myDeveloperDirectory
```

and

```
Xcode-select --install
```

and

```
xcrun swift
```

And I get

```
 error: invalid developer directory
```

and

```
error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

and

```
error: failed to launch REPL process: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)
```

Respectively

Not sure why I can't get this to work

Comment: Can you try `Software Update` command for install updates?

Comment: softwareupdate --install -a fixed it. I do not understand why since "command line tools are already installed" but whatever

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your privileges set correctlY?

Have you read this: https://github.com/apple/swift-docker/issues/9

Comment: That was a fascinating read. Apparently --privileged is the key. And I would of tried that but despite "command line tools already installed" I tried softwareupdate --install -a just for the why not factor and it worked. Although now I wish I read that first because now I'm just going to go with "whatever... I don't get it... but it works..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this solution worked since "command line tools are already installed" but this fixed it for me:

```
softwareupdate --install -a
```

Although I definitely recommend anyone who runs into the same problem to give the link SDGary posted a read.